# Преобразование кода в символы

Tags: c#

Как преобразовать код в символы, уже только какие костыли не приделал все равно что то да не работает

Пробовал так..

```
namespace test
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            //1 вариант
            string[] arrayCode = {"6c", "52"};
            Console.WriteLine (Encoding.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToInt32(arrayCode[0]))));
            //2 вариант
            Encoder.ToChar(arrayCode[i]);
         }
    }
}
```

Выдает ошибку

```
1) an object reference is required to access non-static member 
2) коды русских символов не помещаются в char, тут ошибка превышения размера
```

1 - Не понимаю что он хочет(
2 - Может это можно решить через char?

Comment: Покажите код, куда и в каком методе присваиваете значение первого куска. Ругается на то, что ссылка ожидает доступа к НЕ-статическому члену

Comment: А что у вас в `arrayCode`?

Comment: какие коды предполагается конвертировать? Unicode, ASCII, Utf8?

Comment: @Ep1demic добавил код в тело вопроса.. не понятно мне что куда ссылается..

Comment: @rdorn unicode and utf8

Comment: @VladD обновил тело вопроса..

Comment: Окей. А это коды символов в какой кодировке? ASCII?

Comment: для приведенного примера вполне работает `Console.WriteLine((char)0x6c);`

Comment: @VladD Вамш вопрос мне не понятен, коды символов ни в какой кодировке, код есть код, символы с такими кодами есть и в unicode and utf8 and ASCII так что я не понял вопроса.. Поясните если не сложно

Comment: @ВладимирАлександров: Не бывает кодов символов вне кодировки. Символы сами по себе числового представления не имеют. Один и тот же символ кодируется различными байтами в, например, UTF-8 и UTF-16.

Comment: @ВладимирАлександров собственно все проблемы с кодировками из-за того что в разных кодировках коды символов разные. Исключение классическая 7-и битная ASCII (латинский алфавит, цифры, знаки препинания + немного спецзнаков россыпью)  - она везде одинаковая

Comment: @VladD теперь понял.. Огромное спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @ВладимирАлександров: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

```
string[] arrayCode = {"6c", "52"};
var bytes = arrayCode.Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16));
var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes.ToArray());
```

(для UTF-8).

---

Если в строках не байты, а целые символы, по идее пойдёт такой код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] arrayCode = {"6c", "52", "90d0"};
    var chars = arrayCode.Select(s => ExtractChar(s, Encoding.UTF8));
    var result = new string(chars.ToArray());
}

static char ExtractChar(string s, Encoding enc)
{
    var code = Convert.ToInt32(s, 16);
    var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(code);
    var nbytes = (s.Length + 1) / 2;
    var result = enc.GetString(bytes, 0, nbytes);
    if (result.Length != 1)
        throw new ArgumentException("В строке не один символ");
    return result[0];
}
```

Comment: добавь тогда и для стандартного unicode в .net, там можно просто каст к char сделать

Comment: @rdorn: Каст в char неконцептуально, я бы написал единообразно `Encoding.Unicode.GetString`, чтобы не было соблазна использовать этот код для другой кодировки тоже.

Comment: и ведь не поспоришь =)

Comment: @rdorn: Ну и непонятно, для случая стандартного Unicode, у ТС будут закодированы `short`'ы или `byte`'ы.

Comment: @VladD еще вопрос.. а как быть с русскими буквами? Например с "2DE0" (11744) он явно выходит за рамки байта, и коомпилятор ругается на меня..

Comment: @ВладимирАлександров: Окей, в этом случае вопрос, в какой это кодировке, и что это: байты или отдельные символы? UTF-8 кодирует в байтовые последовательности.

Comment: @VladD это отдельные символы.. каждая позиция в массиве это отдельный символ.. в UTF8  от 0 до FFFFF вроде...

Comment: @ВладимирАлександров: Ага, хорошо, сейчас напишу ещё вариант.

Comment: @ВладимирАлександров: Подождите, а 2DE0 — это _какой_ русский символ? У меня не получается его интерпретировать как UTF-8, получается не русский символ, а что-то странное. Вот таблица: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1024

Comment: @VladD извиняюсь видимо напутал что-то, я накинул свой вариант на основе вашего для отвязки от ограничения, посомтрите это человеческий вид? var intArray = arrayCode.Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s));
byte[] byteArray;
string result;
foreach (var value in intArray) {
byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes (value);
result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString (byteArray.ToArray ());
Console.Write (result);}

Comment: @ВладимирАлександров: Написал обновление ответа

Comment: @VladD класс, еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @ВладимирАлександров: Пожалуйста! Проверяйте на ваших строках, чтобы работало.